# When to use automatic function execution

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

For below piece of code, I am aware that its an **automatic function execution** code (I saw it being used in`JQuery`).

```
var f = function() {

  // function body code
  // ...
  // ...

}();
```

What I want to understand is its usage.

1. Under which all scenarios we should prefer to use above syntax?
2. What are the advantages/benefits do we get by using above syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Comment: @RickRunyon, My question is different than the one you mentioned. I wanted to understand its usage scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"***Immediately invokable function expression***" is the right name for it. And its usages are many, basically it will tightly wrap the `scope` and will not permit access to its `variable` to outside scope unless we are intentionally doing it.

And you can build `singleton pattern` by using it. One of the usages of Singleton pattern is to amend `data encapsulation`. Like `setters` and `getters`.

Possible usage situation:

```
<script src="someLibrary.js"></script> //And it uses a global variable called x
<script>
  var x = 10; //Now at this situation, 
              //the x belongs to someLibrary will be overridden here.
</script>
```

So in order to avoid such conflicts, we can use IIFE,

```
<script>
  (function(){
    var x = 10; 
    .
    .
    //Other codes goes here.
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: *"Singleton pattern is nothing but implementing data encapsulation"* - Um...there's a little more to it than that. And indeed a singleton object could have methods but no data of its own.

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah `nothing but` should have been removed. I was just trying to say an usage of IIEF by quoting singleton pattern. :)

Comment: _"it will tightly wrap the scope and will not permit access to its variable to outside scope"_ - The normal functional will also not allow access to its variables outside its scope. I didn't understand you.

Comment: @A.R. Yes. `var func = function(){ var x; }` is equal to `(function(){ })();`. Except one thing, that is normal function can be called multiple times in other places also. But IIEF cannot.